# Is there exist a general method to compute all real proper integral? If not, what is the theorem that give the negative result?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is there exist a general method to compute all real proper integral that has real variables into another form? If not, what is the theorem that give the negative result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not exist an analytic answer to all integrals, but all bounded (i.e. non-infinite) real integrals can be approximated by an appropriate quadrature to varying degrees of precision and accuracy. [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) places some restrictions on what can be evaluated in terms of elementary functions.

Usually if a non-elementary integral comes up often it is given a special function to simplify it in expressions involving it, e.g:

- [Exponential Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), commonly denoted $\operatorname{Ei}(x)=-\int_{-x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\:\mathrm{d}t$
- [Sine Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_integral#Sine_integral)/[Cosine Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_integral#Cosine_integral) (e.g. $\operatorname{Si}(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\:\mathrm{d}t$)
- [Error Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), $\operatorname{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}\:\mathrm{d}t$

Several methods you might be interested in looking at are:

- [Simpson's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule)
- [Gaussian Quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature)
- [Adaptive Quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_quadrature)

Answer (score 1):

The (Riemann) integral of $f$  will exist only when the set of discontinuities of $f$ has measure zero. If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ , then it  satisfies the conditions of the fundamental theorem of Calculus, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus.

Comment: Can you give a example that shows your statement is true?

Comment: Sure: Consider the characteristic function of the Rationals, or of the Irrationals, i.e., $f(x)=1$ for x in $\mathbb Q$, and $0$ for x in $\mathbb R-Q$ , or $f(x)=1$ for x in $\mathbb R-Q$ and $f(x)=0$ for x in $\mathbb Q$.